# How to play uploaded videos in an iframe on a Mac system

Tags: macos, google-chrome, iframe, html5-video

I have tried using iframe and also video tag and object tag to play the video. In some cases, it plays only the audio from the video, but video doesn't show up.
Secondly, the same video file plays well on a separate tab in the browser, but not within my iframe.
This issue is on all browsers on my Mac, but on a windows machine it plays well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. Apple has a good documentation of its own for this. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/quicktime/conceptual/qtscripting_html/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-GettingaBrowsertoLoadQuickTime

I simply had to use the embed tag properly as they have explained.