# Jquery code not working in mac os chrome but working in windows 10 chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on image then image hide and YouTube video auto play its working fine in windows 10 but not working in mac os / ios.

So need help how to solve this issue.

I don't have mac book my client have so check my friend mac book is there any console log error but there is no error .

**Html**

```
<div class="video_youtube">
              <div class="play_btn"><img src="images/video_bg.png" alt=""></div>
              <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="420"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O3sKoVfpzFI?fs=0&modestbranding=1&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&rel=0"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".play_btn").click(function () {
        $(".play_btn").hide();
        var symbol = $("#ytplayer")[0].src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?";
        $("#ytplayer")[0].src += symbol + "autoplay=1";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Cross-Origin Requests being blocked, this example will not fully work. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.framePlay = function(u) {
    if ($(this).prop("nodeName") == "IFRAME") {
      console.log("Play Triggered", u);
      $(this).attr("src", u);
    }
  };

  $(".play_btn").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    var plyr = $(this).next("iframe");
    var src = plyr.attr("src");
    plyr.framePlay(src + (src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?") + "autoplay=1");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_youtube">
  <div class="play_btn"><img src="images/video_bg.png" alt="Play"></div>
  <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="420" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O3sKoVfpzFI?fs=0&modestbranding=1&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

This creates a custom Function that can be used to update the Source of an iFrame element. It has a single URL Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 Option: Refer Apple Document

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/quicktime/conceptual/qtscripting_html/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-GettingaBrowsertoLoadQuickTime

**SO Question:**
[How to play uploaded videos in an iframe on a Mac system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327840/how-to-play-uploaded-videos-in-an-iframe-on-a-mac-system)

## 2 Option: Try to use Embed object tag for video play

**SO Question:**

[Making youtube.com/embed URLs work on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969334/making-youtube-com-embed-urls-work-on-ios)

[youtube embed video not working with safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494102/youtube-embed-video-not-working-with-safari)

## 3 Option: Use javascript instead of Jquery

*Not tested!*

I would suggest javascript instead of JQuery, here i have converted your code into javascript:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("play_btn");

var play = function() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    var symbol = document.getElementById("ytplayer").src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?";
    document.getElementById("ytplayer").src += symbol + "autoplay=1";
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', play, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_youtube">
    <div class="play_btn"><img src="images/video_bg.png" alt="Play"></div>
    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="420"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O3sKoVfpzFI?fs=0&modestbranding=1&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&rel=0"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` in your function will not have `style` as an index.

Comment: Hi @Viking, i have not tested but, there are other similar questions added link in post, please refer.